# External wifi adapter (TL-WN821N) can't turn to monitor mode

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, ifconfig

I installed the drivers of this device and it works

```
iwconfig
```

here i got:

```
wlan1     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

but i can't switch it to "monitor mode":

```
ifconfig wlan1 down
iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor
```

i got an error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlan1 ; Invalid argument.
```

TL-WN821N 's chip : Realtek RTL8192EU. I'm wondering if it doesn't support "monitor mode" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify if your wifi card support the monitor mode through the `iw` command.

There is an example:

```
 iw list | grep "Supported interface modes" -A10
```

sample output ( the `monitor` mode is supported ) :

```
    Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * WDS
     * monitor
     * mesh point
     * P2P-client
     * P2P-GO
     * outside context of a BSS
```